# How to store only valid data in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am building a timetable system using Firestore as a database (and Angular v9.). I need a way to store only VALID data in the database.

I realize that with Firestore rules, I can set rules for providing access to the user to read or write. But how do I check if the value being stored is correct or VALID? For example, in my case, check if the slot is already assigned. So that when a new slot is being added, it doesn't overlap...

Do I need a server or a proxy or cloud functions? Or is it possible in Firestore directly? Or perform the validation in the frontend only? I believe that checking the data in the frontend would be the worst way to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the validations you're trying to perform can't be done in security rules, then you will need to provide your own backend the exposes APIs for your app to use.  Instead of adding the data directly to the database, it would send the document data for the backend to validate and add.  You can certainly use Cloud Functions for this (and a full discussion is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow answer), but you have essentially unlimited options here.

Comment: Hmm... Okay... I've tried searching for days now whether I've been missing on some part that allows me to validate the data... Seems like I'll have to write my own backend... Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of data validations to be done in security rules. For example, you can make sure a value is an integer, and within some boundary values.  You just can't do everything that could be done with normal code, and you don't have access to very many resources.

Comment: Also, I am not able to discuss the specifics of the app, but would you suggest Cloud Functions or serverless architecture over servers? The main goal being scalability and flexibility. The app may become quite complex with analytics, etc.

Comment: I suggest researching for options that meet your particular needs.  There is no one solution that works for everyone.  Stack Overflow is not a place for soliciting opinions about product choices.